# Get Last (5 or 10) value from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in `Android` and I want to get last `5` or `10` `messages` from `FirebaseDatabase`.I've tried by using this.

---

```
ChatInteractor.databaseReference.orderByKey().startAt(10).endAt(20).addListenerForSingleValueEvent((ValueEventListener) ActivityChatView.this);
```

---

- But it give me `NullPointerException` as a result.
- `Logcat`

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.Query com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.orderByKey()' on a null object reference
```

---

- My `DatabaseStructure` is this

---

[image]

---

- After `updating`

---

```
   DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://afdbjkaffirebaseio.com/");
        Query query=databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).orderByChild("tKyhXXAf6TQnQgKyAf23RJcwhsn1_S5ClzMeWUEXR9evLJO9CBd9ABCH3").limitToLast(2);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat=snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    Log.e("163","ACV"+chat.fromEmail);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

---

- result of `Log`

---

```
 E/163: ACVnull
```

Comment: there is limitTo in firebase have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code as shown below:

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query=databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child("tKyhXXAf6TQnQgKyAf23RJcwhsn1_S5ClzMeWUEXR9evLJO9CBd9ABCH3").orderByChild().limitToLast("Number of last messages you want to show");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat=snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                Log.e("163","ACV"+chat.fromEmail);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DatabaseReference messagesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat_rooms").child("tKyhXXAf6TQnQgKyAf23RJcwhsn1_S5ClzMeWUEXR9evLJO9CBd9ABCH3");  
 Query chatQuery = messagesReference.orderByChild("your key").limitToLast(5);
     chatQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
    //do what ever required 
    }
```

Hope this helps. Please try.

Comment: i've also tried by using this,but it `return null` @yashaswi i am also updated my code can you review my code

Comment: @VishalYadav please check the edited answer for the null exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use Query for this and that could be

```
    @Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    // [START recent_posts_query]
    // Last 1000 posts, these are automatically the 1000 most recent
    // due to sorting by push() keys
    Query recentPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("posts")
            .limitToLast(number of post you want);
    // [END recent_posts_query]

    return recentPostsQuery;
}
```

this will give you post limited by number you given.
you can get more info from **Firebase official docs** or their **github repo**
[Firebase link of github of fragment repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/fragment)

hope this will help.......

Comment: Tried but gives me `null` i do'nt know what i missed